# Stripy HTML tables and rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

Original table (http://highspeedbroadband.com.my/home-package/comparison-chart-for-home-package/)

I want to modify the original as highlighted in image below. I can do this by adding rowspan and colspan attribute to td elements but when I use row span in stripy tables the order of alternative color breaks and gives me ugly result.

someone help me please.

[image: stripy table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping those three texts with another `table` in which every *FREE xmins* will be a new table cell (`<td>`) like this:

```
(...)
<td colspan="3">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>FREE 50 mins</td>
            <td>FREE 100 mins</td>
            <td>FREE 200 mins</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
(...)
```

Comment: Adding an block element (`table`) inside a inline element (`td`) isn't allowed, unless it's HTML5, but since that isn't tagged...

Comment: Did you see the `DOCTYPE` in OP's website?

Comment: I don't just click random links, but checked it, you are right. (hmm, can't see to undo my downvote)

Comment: Now you can. I had to edit my answer. [Here's the explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139949/unable-to-undo-downvote).

Answer (score 0):

You could make 3 spans inside the cell.

HTML:

```
<td>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
table td span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/HvZvQ/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<td colspan="3" id="TD_97"> <div class="xyz">
    <div class="abc">   &nbsp;FREE 50mins  </div>
<div class="abc">   FREE  100mins  </div>
<div class="abc">   FREE 200mins  </div>

       <div class="aa">   *RM0.15/min (local fixed and mobile call)</div> </div>
                </td>
```

CSS

```
  .xyz{
height: 168px;
    line-height: 21px;
    outline: rgb(81, 94, 108) none 0px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  float:right;
    width: 250px;
}
.abc {
    float:left;
    width:77px;
    height:100px;
    padding-top:50px;
    border:double 3px black;
}
.aa {
    border-top:none;
    border:double 3px black;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
    clear:both;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IQopUpU/1/)